# First order differential equation problem hint needed

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

As part of my research I get the following differential equation. I need to solve for $\mathcal V(\gamma)$. In fact the requirement is not to solve but to show that $\mathcal V(\gamma)$ is monotonic in $a_j$ $\forall j$, (which I hope it is) where $a_j$ are positive valued constants which do not depend on $\gamma$. If it can be shown without solving the differential equation that is sufficient. Please provide some suggestions.
$$
\cfrac{\gamma}{\log\left(e\right)}\cfrac{d}{d\gamma}\mathcal{V}\left(\gamma\right)=1-\eta\left(\gamma\right)
$$
$$
\eta\left(\gamma\right)=\cfrac{1}{1+\gamma\sum_{j}\cfrac{a_{j}}{1-a_{j}\left(-\gamma\eta\left(\gamma\right)\right)}}
$$ where $j=\{1,\dots,n\}$.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that $\eta_a(\gamma)$ solves the equation $F_\gamma(\eta_a(\gamma),a)+n=1$ where
$$
F_\gamma(h,a)=h-\sum_i\frac1{1+\gamma ha_i}.
$$
Each function $F_\gamma(\ ,a)$ is increasing. Each function $F_\gamma(h,\ )$ is increasing. Hence $a\mapsto\eta_a(\gamma)$ is decreasing, for each $\gamma$. This proves that $a\mapsto \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\gamma}V_a(\gamma)$ is increasing.

Thus, assuming that there exists some $\gamma_0$ such that $V_a(\gamma_0)$ does not depend on $a$, one sees that $a\mapsto V_a(\gamma)$ is increasing if $\gamma\gt\gamma_0$ and decreasing if $\gamma\lt\gamma_0$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that it would be separable as the right hand side is only a function of $\gamma$, so I want to say just integrate as,
$$\nu = \int \frac{\log(e)}{\gamma}[1-\eta(\gamma)]d\gamma + C.$$ However, I'm not sure how you're going to rectify $\eta(\gamma)$. Because of the summation, it doesn't seem hopeful that you'd be able to get an explicit expression for $\eta$ to substitute into the integral... Are you solely interested in an analytical solution?

Cheers,

Paul Safier

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I need an analytical solution to claim that the function is monotonic in $a_i$s. I do not necessarily need a solution for $\mathcal V$.